# WebPacker - Load NPM modules via ES6 Import vs webpack.ProvidePlugin()

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am experimenting with running multiple WebApps inside of Rails.

Each WebApp has totally different dependencies and I would like to keep the bundle sizes of each to minimum size.

The first app I am building uses [Reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/) and I have added it using `yarn add reveal`

I had thought I could include it by importing via packs/presentation.js

```
console.log('Presentation System');
import 'reveal';

Reveal.initialize({
  controls: true,
  progress: true,
  history: true,
  center: true,
  transition: 'none',
});
```

[image]

I then tried a slight variation `import { Reveal } from 'reveal';`

```
  console.log('Presentation System');
  import { Reveal } from 'reveal';

  Reveal.initialize({
    controls: true,
    progress: true,
    history: true,
    center: true,
    transition: 'none',
  });
```

[image]

I finally got Reveal.js to work by altering the WebPacker config in side rails

> config/webpack/environment.js

I added in jQuery and Reveal.js as webpack plugins by using the following code

I am unsure whether this is the best way to include reveal as it seems like it would effect all my apps by adding jQuery and Reveal to each app which is not what I want as the other apps are using VUE or Angular

```
// https://joey.io/how-to-use-jquery-in-rails-5-2-using-webpack/
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');
const typescript =  require('./loaders/typescript');
const vue =  require('./loaders/vue');

const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.loaders.append('vue', vue);
environment.loaders.append('typescript', typescript);

module.exports = environment;

environment.plugins.prepend(
    'Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery',
      Reveal: 'reveal'
    })
);
```

And the code that I now run to display the presentation

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  Reveal.initialize({
    controls: true,
    progress: true,
    history: true,
    center: true,
    transition: 'none',
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `import Reveal from 'reveal'` ?

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/learn/#modules

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

By doing `import { Reveal } from 'reveal'` you are trying to import a `Reveal` named export of the `Reveal` module.

But `Reveal` is the `default` export.

Comment: I am sure I tried that, but I will check soon, thanks for the reply

Comment: Thanks that worked, time to do some es6 tutorials I think